# Error: Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.disable_ahardware_buffer"

Tags: debugging, flutter

I'm an advanced beginner, self-learning, currently learning how to build an app with Flutter/Dart. I have the above message in my Visual Studio Code debug console after making a change to my code to center a network image. I am using my phone for debugging, code ran successfully prior to center. I've googled the message both with and without quotes, with quote five results which I didn't find helpful, without quotes 10 results which aren't pertinent.

What else can I tell you? Thanks for the help.

````
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Reloaded 1 of 440 libraries in 1,455ms.
I/OpenGLRenderer(29193): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(29193): Swap behavior 2
W/RenderThread(29193): type=1400 audit(0.0:1932): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=21490 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c218,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc    (29193): Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.disable_ahardware_buffer"
Reloaded 0 of 440 libraries in 359ms.```
````

Comment: So, if you remove the `center` widget, does it works ?

Comment: Image renders, debug console shows: ```Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 3a XL in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/OpenGLRenderer(12080): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(12080): Swap behavior 2
E/libc    (12080): Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.disable_ahardware_buffer"
W/RenderThread(12080): type=1400 audit(0.0:2121): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=21490 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c218,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0```

Comment: When I updated the code for center again and did a hot reload I got the same message. But when I did a restart (instead of hot reload) the message disappeared and the image correctly rendered in the center.Error is apparently solved but I welcome education as to what the access denial message means so I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the comments, it looks like the issue was resolved by running an app restart. Given that the issue was fixed by running a restart, it's likely that there's an app state retained that might've caused the error.

With the given details, it's difficult to determine the cause of this issue. If anyone is having similar errors, please file it here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/